# try/finally results in exception

Tags: delphi

A method is called to an external C/C++ library that returns a pointer to a Delphi XE6 application. There is then a try/finally block and in the finally the memory allocated by the C/C++ library is released. If I release the memory in the finally I get a privileged instruction exception at the free. If I free the memory outside the try/finally block, there are no exception.

```
// This crashes
ptr := CMethod();

try
  // 
finally
  freeCPtr (ptr);
end

// This doesn't crash
ptr := CMethod();
freeCPtr (ptr)
```

Note that the freeCPtr() is a method exported by the C library and is designed to free pointers returned by CMethod(). CMethod() and freeCPtr() have been shown to work without issue inside a C application by two independent third-party  developers. I am curious to know why the use of try/finally might cause an exception?

**UPDATE** It turns out that the authors of the original C/C++ library had changed their calling convention from stdcall to cdecl. Normally I check calling conventions first when ever there are issues but I knew that previous code I had worked fine and so didn't initially consider checking the calling conventions. Moral of the story is, whenever one gets odd behavior when calling external libraries check: 1) Calling conventions are compatible; 2) You're passing the correct types to the external libraries.

Comment: I should clarify, the freeptr() function is exported by the C library.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah okay that is better. I thought it was a function on the Delphi side ;-).

Comment: Does freeCPtr throw exceptions from the C side?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that on the `C` side there is a problem with freeing and allocation (some subtle bug?) that manifests itself in certain circumstances. For instance allocating memory with C++ `new` operator and freeing it with `free` instead of `delete`

Comment: I just got word from one of the developers of the C/C++ code, if the free function is empty on the C side we still see an exception. I should also note that this used to work on Delphi XE, this is the first time I've tried it with XE6. I'm going to try this again on XE to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay that rules out that theory. Okay so maybe the obvious. Are you using the same calling convention? Not sure what you have defined on the C side or the Delphi side. If they are incompatible then you'd see strange stack weirdness that would cause problems. Since `freeCPtr` doesn't have to do anything to cause this issue I can only assume calling convention mismatch. My opinion is the try/finally is a red herring and a symptom of another root problem.

Comment: On the Delphi side I am using the same calling convention as before, stdcall. I just tried it on XE and it also failed, that's news to me. I therefore think some change has happened on the C/C++ side, possibly a calling convention change. At this stage I don't think it is delphi bug which I had wondered. I shall investigate further.

Comment: I guess the thing to do is create minimal C++ code that produces the fault and investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to see what is the problem, but to my experience, unexplainable problems like these, that works in one version and not the other, and especially when there are calls to external C/C++ .dll:s, arise when optimization is set to on.

Make sure that optimization is not set to on in in the project settings or profile you are using and see if that makes any difference. Using {$Optimization Off} in the unit itself works also, of course.

I realize that this perhaps is more of a comment than an answer, but I am such a SO newbie that I don't have that many points. :-)

Comment: I tried and short answer is no. Instead I decided to take some other advice that was given I shot news and write a small c/c++ dll to test the problem on. This worked fine. I then started wondering whether the authors of the original code had changed something. It turns out that the previous developer had changed the calling convention without telling anyone. In the end the problem was solved by changing stdcal to cdecl at my end!

Comment: Oh, that's annoying. Well, nice to hear it worked out. 
If you like, you can add an update to your question with the "solution" or an answer so that other people don't have to read all these comments to get an answer.